# Show both values of a pair of an object with ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects which looks like this:

```
myCtrl.siteNameLabels = myCtrl.actual.map(function (value, index) {
    return {
        actualSite: {
            actualSiteName : value,
            actualSiteData:  myCtrl.tableData[index]
        },
        pastSite: {
            pastSiteName : myCtrl.pastSiteNameLabels[index] + "_past",
            pastSiteData : myCtrl.tableDataPast[index]
        }
    }
})
```

There are pairs of the same site (present , past) each of them having a name which is the same for both (the past has "past" at the end for identification), and data to show on the screen (which is an array of numeric values).

Each site has data for present but there are sites that don't have data for past.

I must put all these data inside a table header which could look like this:

```
Site1 | Site1_past | Site2 | Site3 | Site3_past | Site4
```

If I only had the present sites it would be very easy to put the data using an `ng-repeat`. The problem is that I also have the optional past sites which must be put in pair with their present site.

This is my code for generating for present sites:

```
<thead>
    <tr>    
        <th ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.siteNameLabels">{{label.actual.actualSiteName}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.tableData[0] track by $index">
        <td>{{$ctrl.dateLabels[$index]}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.actualSiteNameLabels">{{$ctrl.tableData[$index][$parent.$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It shows it like this:

```
Site1 |  Site2 | Site3 | Site4
```

Any ideas how to make it like this?

```
Site1 | Site1_past | Site2 | Site3 | Site3_past | Site4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to store site value

```
    site: {
        actualSiteName : value,
        actualSiteData:  myCtrl.tableData[index]
        pastSiteName : myCtrl.pastSiteNameLabels[index] + "_past",
        pastSiteData : myCtrl.tableDataPast[index]
    }
```

Hope it won't affect other functionality...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var labelList = [{ actualName: "Site1", pastName: "Site1_past" },
                 { actualName: "Site2" },
                 { actualName: "Site3", pastName: "Site3_past" },
                 { actualName: "Site4" },
                ];

var flatList = [];
labelList.forEach(function(item) {
    flatList.push(item.actualName);
    if (item.pastName) {
        flatList.push(item.pastName);
    };
});
console.log(flatList);
```